# How to use FindIterable<Document> to get the specific field from mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb

Here,I'm trying to retrieve the status field if the name matches.How to use FindIterable instead of DBCursor.Can anyone please help me out ...

My code:

```
  public String getStatus(String name) throws Exception{
             MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
             MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("counter");
             MongoCollection<Document> col = db.getCollection("status");

            Document query = new Document();
            query.put("name", name);
            query.put("status", 1);

            Document fields = new Document();
            fields.put("status", 1);
            fields.put("_id", 0);

             DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query,fields);

             while(cursor.hasNext()){
                    System.out.println(cursor.next());
                }

        return "SUCCESS";
        }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You simply load the cursor into a FindIterable object like so:

```
FindIterable<Document> docs = col.find(query);
if (docs == null) {
    //no values found
}

for(Document doc : docs) {
    //access documents e.g. doc.get()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply load the cursor and fetch the document into the Document. for more info visit https://dzone.com/articles/basic-java-crud-operations

```
DBCursor cursor = items.find(query);
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    Document document = cursor.next();
    System.out.println(document.getString("identifier"));
}
```